# Control push button

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to use a push button control so that when selected (the White circle in the middle turns black) a certain action takes place.  Likewise, i would like a different action to take place when the button is un-selected (the White circle returns White).  I am having trouble understanding what the name of the two events would be.  I originally thought that "mouse down" and "mouse up" was the answer but it is not the case. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at `onclick`?

Comment: `If Me.Option0 = True Then
    MsgBox "Clicked"
Else
    MsgBox "Not clicked"
End If`

Comment: but onlclick only gives me one option.. I need two.

Comment: @ remou.  are you saying that the control when selected has a true value and when un selected has a false value?

Comment: Thanks Remou! You hit the nail on the head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If me.option0= true then MsgBox "Clicked" Else MsgBox "Not Clicked" End If